# Сборка приложения для windows с использованием visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++builder, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток!

Разрабатываю понемножку с использовванием visual studio(13), и постоянно мучит особенность сборки под винду, которая заключается в следующем: для корректной работы на другом компьютере необходимо ручками докладывать библиотеки, которые приложение просит на выходе. В то же время, когда приложение собирается в релизе и запускается, то студия автоматически подкадывает нужные библиотеки, что б приложение могло запуститься.

Что необходимо сделать для того что бы студия скопировала все необходимые для работы библиотеки в папку рядом с ехе-шником?

Comment: Они вообще-то там и лежат. Иначе бы и из-под отладчика не запустилось. Вы смотрите где-то не там.

Comment: О каких библиотеках речь - статических иди динамических? Есть ли в самом приложении загрузка DLL? На .NET писано или нет?

Comment: Говорю о динамических библиотеках(dll), при рассматривании в наиболее простом случае в проекте не подключаем ни одну внешнюю библиотеку, однако для корректного запуска не из компилятора рядом надо положить ряд библиотек, которые - как подозреваю - содержат подключаемые хедеры. Для qt один добрый  товаришч [Avazart](http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/131347/blog2457.html) написал dllcollector - программу, которая подкидывает нужные длл-файлы к исполняемому ехе-шнику. Наверняка в студии есть что-либо аналогичное?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Стандартно, в студии ничего подобного не предусмотрено. Предпологается, что разработчик сам знает какие библиотеки используются в его проекте и сам ими управляет.

Однако, есть библиотеки которые могут линковаться неявно, при этом способ линковки (статическая/динамическая) можно настраивать в параметрах проекта:

1. CRT - настраивается параметром "C/C++\Code Generation\Runtime Library", по-умолчанию включена динамическая линковка и именно из-за нее у новичков возникают проблемы при распространении ПО; если включить статическую линковку то DLL тянуть не потребуется.
2. MFC - настраивается "General\Use of MFC", по-умолчанию не используется
3. ATL - настраивается "General\Use of ATL", по-умолчанию не используется

Проблема в том, что на машине разработчика все эти библиотеки устанавливатся вместе со студией и поэтому ПО запускается из любого места. А вот на машине пользователя этих библиотек часто нет, от сюда у новичков и возникают проблемы. Проблема решается либо статической линковкой, либо установкой соответсвующих пакетов (редистов) нужных версий (ссылки успешно яндексятся на сайте Майкрософта)

Вторая проблема в том, что при автоматической загрузке DLL, требуется чтобы все библиотеки в пределах одного бинаря линковались одинаково. Это означает, например, что если QT слинковам с CRT динамически то и наш бинарь должен линковать CRT динамически. Это можно обойти, если применять не автоматическую а ручную загрузку DLL, но тогда гемор разрастется многократно. Проще немного увеличить инсталянт в размере, може мне поверить.

Answer (score 7):

1. Для корректной работы на другом компьютере, при настройках сборки по умолчанию (то есть с ключом **/MD**), нужно установить [Microsoft VC++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=40784) (2013, в данном случае), корректной архитектуры (x86 или amd64, в зависимости от настроек сборки).
2. Класть эти файлы (msvcxxx120.dll) в папку приложения абсолютно **некорректно**, ибо нарушается механизм их корректной регистрации в системе и обновления (На машинах с включенным Windows Update VC++ redistributables сами обновляются, в папке же приложения останутся старые версии, в том числе с неустраненными уязвимостями)
3. Некорректно распространять Debug-версии этих файлов (при сборке в Debug-конфигурации, с ключом **/MDd**, используются версии библиотек с d на конце (msvcr120d.dll), соответственно перед распространением приложения нужно убедиться что включена Release-конфигурация.
4. Для простого приложения, состоящего из одного exe-файла, зависимости от CRT-библиотек можно избежать, собрав с ключом **/MT**, что незначительно увеличит приложение в размере, однако при сложном приложении, состоящем из множества библиотек - в размере увеличится **каждая** библиотека, и выигрыш теряется.
5. При использовании сторонних библиотек/фреймворков (Qt, boost, и т.д.) следует проследить, что их библиотеки собраны в точном соответствии с конфигурацией приложения - приложение, собранное с **/MD** при попытке использования Qt, собранного с **/MT** и наоборот (а так же если сторонняя библиотека собрана с другой версией CRT, например msvcr90.dll) практически гарантировано вызовет [ошибки и вылеты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Помогло указывание в свойствах проекта /MT (/MTd):
   Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threaded (/MT) (или Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd))
2. а также указывание платформы Windows XP:
   Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset -> Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)