# Компиляция Visual C++ без зависимости dll

Tags: visual-c++, vc++2015

Подскажите, как компилировать приложения с помощью Microsoft Studio Visual C++, чтобы при работе скомпилированных приложений не требовалось установка Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package, т.е. без зависимости сторонних библиотек.

Интересует на примере проекта [pngwolf-zopfli](https://github.com/jibsen/pngwolf-zopfli)

Comment: Формально ваш вопрос не копия, но все ответы уже есть в другом вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424350/180450

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку! но честно говоря я так и не понял, как применить данные ключи конкретно для моего проекта.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал все таки рассмотреть вариант с Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package, например, если будете использовать сторонние dll, которые все равно будут иметь эту зависимость.